# usecontext returns undefined during api calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the below code and I have an issue with calling API call using usecontext in react. Guide me to fix it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-williamson-bbik6?file=/src/App.js

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

const JediContext = React.createContext();

function Display() {
  const value = useContext(JediContext);
  return <div>{value.total}, I am your Father.</div>;
}

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(0);
  fetch("https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=react")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((rawData) => {
      console.log(data);
      setData(rawData);
    });
  return (
    <JediContext.Provider value={data.total}>
      <Display />
    </JediContext.Provider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: You need `useState({total: 0});` to set the initial value for the very first render.  I encountered a second problem but I don't think it's related.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with the posted code:

1. You are accessing `total` in the `Display` component, while passing `data.total` in the `JediContext.Provider`. I think you intended to pass just `data`.
2. `fetch` runs with every render so your page with keep re-rendering since you are `setData(rawData)` after `fetch` is done. This will cause an infinite loop and crash the application. It is common practice (at this point in time), to use `useEffect` to fetch data. In the future, `suspense`[1](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html) might be used for this purpose but that's experimental now.
3. One of the error you were getting was because `JediContext` didn't have a default value. So `value.total` produces a null pointer exception. To provide a default value to the context, `const JediContext = React.createContext(/*provide default value here*/);`
4. You already have the

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

in your `index.js`. In `App.js`, you just need to export `App` as a default function.

Here's a version of your code that is kinda working in Codesand box:
https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-worker-bcix4?file=/src/App.js